# Excel apply formula to existing cells value without copy/paste

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file in which there is some data. This year Latvia entered into the Eurozone and Latvian Lats are replaced with Euro. So i need to convert all values from Lats to Euro without copying from one cell to another and then paste it back. All values are static (no formulas are used).

Comment: use formulae to get the equivalent Euro Values at some other location in the sheet/ other sheet and then paste those values over the original.

Comment: I already in question tell, that i do not want that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Start by entering 1.43 in any empty cell in your worksheet (this is the Euro Value of one Lats currently).

[image]

Then copy that value:

[image]

Then select your range with Lats and Right click and select Paste Special:

[image]

On that menu Under operation select Multiply then click Ok:

[image]

and you should end up with the results:

[image]

You can delete the cell that has 1.43 in it when you are done.