# Excel - Use formula/calculation within a Number Format

Tags: excel, excel-formula, number-formatting

How do I put a formula in a Custom Number Format in Excel? For example (random example for illustration purposes),

Assume I have the following data:

**INPUT**

[image]

**OUTPUT**

Without editing the actual data in the cells, I would like to display the value in the cell divided by 2, and with two decimal places:

[image]

Is there a way to do this directly in the Custom Number Format, i.e. Without adding helper columns/cells doing the division calculation. NB. the part that has me stumped is doing the division calculation in the Number Format

Thanks!

Comment: That's not what a number format does. You'll need a formula for that sort of thing.

Comment: If you have simple math operations (add, subtract, multiply, divide) then you can use *paste special* see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21560704/7184815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The answer is NO**, if you want to do it through custom format in a cell directly.

However, there is workaround in pivot table using **calculated field** option as shown below:

[image: Calculated Field]

By the way I am curious why you want to show the number in a value other than its true value in a cell? This is not a good practice which could lead to misuse of the data in my humble opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. More specifically it would be for showing "minutes" as "hours and minutes", eg. displaying 90 as "1h 30m". I was trying to get away from doing "/60/24" in a different cell and then doing a number format on the result. Figured it would save a lot of time and error if there was a way to do it directly in the number format.

Comment: @jblack if you have done the conversion using formula correctly, it will save more time and error than doing it in custom format (if it was ever possible). I think checking a formula in a cell is way easier than checking a formula in custom format window.

Comment: @TerryW have you find any better option? It is not feasible for me to put formulas on each cell as my table is structured in non-conventional manner.

Comment: @HarshilModi if convenient please post your question with sample data and desired result, then you may let me know and I will have a look when I get a chance. It would also be a good idea to show what you have tried so far in your post. Cheers

Comment: @TerryW after posting the previous comment I found another stackoverflow question, and with that I was able to solve my problem. I added link to that answer in the comments under the question

Answer (score 0):

I have been wanting to display my min/60 as minutes, but the decimal is necessary for calculations. The best way I've found so far is to use conditional formatting in fractions.

0/60 "min" would display. 21666666 as 13/60 min
Which is what the cell formula was. It's only useful for around an hours worth of time, but if I come up with something to more clearly display a calculation of such as 8.5hrs as 8hrs 30min I'll update.